# Cypress - testing a contact form with google recaptcha

Tags: recaptcha, cypress

How can I test a contact form with google recaptcha ?

I want to test if "We will respond you soon." message appear.

Comment: Firebase users, see here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.authsettings#authsettingsappverificationdisabledfortesting

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created my own Cypress command in order to test Google reCAPTCHA

```
Cypress.Commands.add('solveGoogleReCAPTCHA', () => {
  // Wait until the iframe (Google reCAPTCHA) is totally loaded
  cy.wait(500);
  cy.get('#g-recaptcha *> iframe')
    .then($iframe => {
      const $body = $iframe.contents().find('body');
      cy.wrap($body)
        .find('.recaptcha-checkbox-border')
        .should('be.visible')
        .click();
    });
});
```

I combined this command with the instructions given by Google:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

So, I had to do minor changes to my source code:

```
export const RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY: string = window.Cypress
  ? '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI'
  : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Comment: I didn't test it but it looks ok.

Comment: @amoninaalvarez - where did you save the captcha salt key and Site key in your script?

Comment: As Jan Paul mentions in his answer, also be sure to set chromeWebSecurity to false in cypress.json, or else cypress won't have access to the iframe contents

Comment: Please provide more information about which files your code changes were made to.

Answer (score 13):

After some attempts, I came up with this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('confirmCaptcha', function () {
  cy.get('iframe')
    .first()
    .then((recaptchaIframe) => {
      const body = recaptchaIframe.contents()
      cy.wrap(body).find('.recaptcha-checkbox-border').should('be.visible').click()
    })
})
```

Also make sure you have this in your `cypress.json` file, otherwise iFrames cannot be accessed:

```json
"chromeWebSecurity": false
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, which has no need for a `cy.wait(500)` or other fixed amount of time, because it uses the cypress implicit wait in `its` for the iframe contents to load.

```
         cy.get('iframe')
            .first()
            .its('0.contentDocument.body')
            .should('not.be.undefined')
            .and('not.be.empty')
            .then(cy.wrap)
            .find('#recaptcha-anchor')
            .should('be.visible')
            .click();
```

This can be added as a custom command as well.  It is based off of this blog post: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/

Comment: This worked for me without the `cy.wait`. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

### `react-google-recaptcha`

if you wan to test `react-google-recaptcha` here is the solution for it:

**cypress/support/commands.ts:**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('solveGoogleReCAPTCHA', () => {
    cy.get('iframe')
        .first()
        .then((recaptchaIframe) => {
            const body = recaptchaIframe.contents()
            cy.wrap(body).find('.recaptcha-checkbox').should('exist').click()
        })
})

// TS type declaration:
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
        solveGoogleReCAPTCHA(value?: string /* eslint-disable-line */): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>
    }
}
```

And add test key to google recaptcha, test key: `6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI`:

```js
<ReCAPTCHA
     sitekey={
       typeof window !== 'undefined' && window?.Cypress
            ? '6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI'
            : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY!
     }
/>
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need in my case 

Answer (score -2):

Cypress has good suggestions on their best practice page: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites

Basically it comes down to this: if it is not your own application, just stub it. Trust the 3th party to test their own page.

Comment: I do not want to test recaptcha; I want to test my application, my form; But there is a recaptcha; how can I be sure that message "We will respond soon." appear after user click Send button ?